# Request that these questions about Warlock spell slots and multiclassing gain a second duplicate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, duplicates

There currently exist both of the following questions:

- [Can I cast a Warlock spell with another (higher) spell slot from a different multiclass?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120421)
- [What level are spells cast at if a warlock multiclasses as another caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59288)

And there are two questions which are marked as duplicates of *both* of these:

- [If I multiclass as a warlock and another class, and I get spell slots from that other class, do they count as my highest-level slot or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122922)
- [Can a multiclassed warlock cast warlock spells on a lower level spellslot from their other class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138849)

There are also four questions which are marked as duplicates *only of the second one*:

- [Warlock and Sorcerer Multiclass Casting With An Enhanced Effect](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139732)
- [D&D 5e Warlock Multiclass - Casting Warlock Spells Using Other Class Spell Slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123524)
- [Warlocks using spell slots with multiclassing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134924)
- [Paladin/Warlock sharing spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61712)

This is just a request that the four directly above be marked as duplicates  of both questions.

Comment: This is indeed the correct way and place to make such a request. Thanks! (I'm looking through everything when I get a chance here)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Is it actually possible to add another dupe tartlet without opening and re-closing the question?

Comment: @ObliviousSage It is indeed possible for diamond moderators at least. Also maybe gold badge holders (but that one I don't remember).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: Yep, pretty sure gold-badge holders can do it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, and I've added [Can I cast a Warlock spell with another (higher) spell slot from a different multiclass?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120421) as a dupe target to:

- [Warlock and Sorcerer Multiclass Casting With An Enhanced Effect](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139732)
- [D&D 5e Warlock Multiclass - Casting Warlock Spells Using Other Class Spell Slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123524)
- [Warlocks using spell slots with multiclassing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134924)
- [Paladin/Warlock sharing spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61712)